# How to write a dictionary with multiple keys, each with multiple values to a csv in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, file-writing

I have a dictionary that looks like this...

```
cla_1results= {"Tom":[1,7,4],"Dunc":[3,9,4],"Jack":[1,3,5]}
```

I want to write this dictionary to a csv so that it is in the following format

Don't have the rep to post images but it would be something like this...

```
Tom,  1, 7, 4
Dunc  3, 9, 4
Jack  1, 3, 5
```

Nothing I've tried has worked. My recent effort is below but I'm a real beginner with Python and programming in general.

```
import csv

cla_1results= {"Tom":[1,7,4],"Dunc":[3,9,4],"Jack":[1,3,5]}
cla_2results = {"Jane":[1,7,4],"Lynda":[3,9,4],"Dave":[1,3,5]}
cla_3results = {"Gemma":[1,7,4],"Steve":[3,9,4],"Jay":[1,3,5]}

b = open ('test.csv','w')
a = csv.writer(b)
data = cla_1results= {"Tom":[1,7,4],"Dunc":[3,9,4],"Jack":[1,3,5]}
a.writerows(data)
b.close()
```

which unfortunately only gives me:

```
T, o, m
D, u, n, c
J, a, c, k
```

etc

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: I've updated the question to show this now EdChum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many ways to do it:

```
import csv

cla_1results = {
    "Tom": [1, 7, 4],
    "Dunc": [3, 9, 4],
    "Jack": [1, 3, 5]
}

with open("test.csv", 'w+') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    for name in cla_1results:
        writer.writerow([name, ] + [i for i in cla_1results[name]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you just needed a list to generate csv file, so it can be generated on the fly as well.

```
import csv
cla_1results= {"Tom":[1,7,4],"Dunc":[3,9,4],"Jack":[1,3,5]}
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for key,value in cla_1results.iteritems():
                writer.writerow([key]+value)
```

Comment: Why the weird settings for delimiter and `quotechar`? Use the defaults!

Comment: Hi, like the look of this but struggling with the same problem with this and kezzos' solution the iteritems() keeps throwing an attribute error?

Comment: cla_1results is a dict, iteritems() is a function which iterates through the dictionary with key, value pairs, The exact code I have writted above works, could you post the exact code which throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DataFrame.from_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) classmethod to convert `dict` to DataFrame and then can use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to convert the dataframe to csv. I have used `header=False` to strip off the headers.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

cla_1results = {"Tom": [1, 7, 4], "Dunc": [3, 9, 4], "Jack": [1, 3, 5]}

df = DataFrame.from_dict(cla_1results, orient='index')

print(df.to_csv(header=False))

Dunc,3,9,4
Jack,1,3,5
Tom,1,7,4
```

Comment: Thanks that's great but I'm trying to do it without installing external modules .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```python
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    c = csv.writer(csvfile)
    line = []
    for key, value in cla.iteritems():
        line.append(key)
        for i in value:
            line.append(i)
        c.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this to and updated the line to reflect my own dictionary name however I don't understand "iteritems()" as "dict" object has no attribute. Probably being. 'for key, value in cla_1results.iteritems'

Comment: I dont understand sorry, it works for me with the example provided

Comment: Apologies it was my mistake, I messed up the naming of the dict

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"Tom":[1,7,4],"Dunc":[3,9,4],"Jack":[1,3,5]}
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, vals in data.items():
        line = ','.join([k] + map(str, vals)) + '\n'
        f.write(line)
```